# PyQt4: How can I avoid this race condition? QThread disconnected before fully started

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pyqt4, race-condition

I have a situation where I would like to use a single QThread to run two (or more) separate methods at different times. For example, I would like the QThread to run `play()` sometimes, and when I am done playing, I want to disconnect the QThread from this method so that I may connect it somewhere else. In essence I would like the QThread to act as a container for anything I would like to run in parallel with the main process.

I have run into the problem where starting the QThread and then immediately disconnecting it causes strange behavior at runtime. Before I discovered what 'race condition' meant (or really understanding much about multithreading), I had the sneaking suspicion that the thread wasn't fully started before being disconnected. To overcome this, I added a 5 ms sleep in between the `start()` and `disconnect()` calls and it works like a charm. It works like a charm but it isn't The Right Way.

**How can I implement this functionality with one QThread without making the call to `sleep()`?**

### Code Snippet in Question:

```
def play(self):

        self.stateLabel.setText("Status: Playback initated ...")

        self.myThread.started.connect(self.mouseRecorder.play)
        self.myThread.start()
        time.sleep(.005)  #This is the line I'd like to eliminate

        self.myThread.started.disconnect()
```

### Full Script:

```
class MouseRecord(QtCore.QObject):

    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()    

    def __init__(self):

        super(MouseRecord, self).__init__()        

        self.isRecording = False
        self.cursorPath = []

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()  
    def record(self):

        self.isRecording = True
        self.cursorPath = []

        while(self.isRecording):

            self.cursorPath.append(win32api.GetCursorPos())
            time.sleep(.02)            

        self.finished.emit()

    def stop(self):

        self.isRecording = False

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def play(self):

        for pos in self.cursorPath:
            win32api.SetCursorPos(pos)
            time.sleep(.02)        

        print "Playback complete!"
        self.finished.emit()            

class CursorCapture(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(CursorCapture, self).__init__()

        self.mouseRecorder = MouseRecord()

        self.myThread = QtCore.QThread()

        self.mouseRecorder.moveToThread(self.myThread)
        self.mouseRecorder.finished.connect(self.myThread.quit)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.recordBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Record")
        self.stopBtn   = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
        self.playBtn   = QtGui.QPushButton("Play")        

        self.recordBtn.clicked.connect(self.record)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.stop)
        self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.stateLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Status: Stopped.")

        #Bunch of other GUI initialization ...

    def record(self):

        self.stateLabel.setText("Status: Recording ...")  

        self.myThread.started.connect(self.mouseRecorder.record)
        self.myThread.start()
        time.sleep(.005)        

        self.myThread.started.disconnect()

    def play(self):

        self.stateLabel.setText("Status: Playback initated ...")

        self.myThread.started.connect(self.mouseRecorder.play)
        self.myThread.start()
        time.sleep(.005)

        self.myThread.started.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to create new `QThread` for each action, this way the `sleep` and disconnecting won't be necessary. Right now, even if you successfully eliminate the `sleep` call, the following scenario is possible:

1) You run `play`, and disconnect the slot

2) You run `record` before `play` has finished. In such situation previously created thread is still running and:

> If the thread is already running, this function does nothing.

(from the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html#start))

If you however accept this scenario and somehow guard against "playing" and "recording" at the same time, then you should do as you wrote yourself: "when I am done playing, I want to disconnect". So, not just after the thread was started, but after it's done. To do this try this:

1) Change `self.mouseRecorder.finished.connect(self.myThread.quit)` to `self.mouseRecorder.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)`

2) Implement:

```
def threadFinished(self):
        self.myThread.quit()
        self.myThread.started.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to start the thread right away and communicate with the `MouseRecorder` instance with signals and slots FROM the gui thread.

You are signaling the `MouseRecorder` instance by starting the `QThread` (which you have the signal hooked up to trigger the specific event). Normally you will want to use that sig/slot connection if you have something that needs to happen only ONCE in a worker thread. Otherwise you will normally do the cross thread communication with any QObjects that get `moveToThread` with signals and slots.

Instead I'd write it as the following:

```
class MouseRecord(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MouseRecord, self).__init__()        
        self.isRecording = False
        self.cursorPath = []

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()  
    def record(self):
        self.isRecording = True
        self.cursorPath = []

        while(self.isRecording):
            #Needed, so that if a sigStop is emitted, self.isRecording will be able to be changed
            QApplication.processEvents()

            self.cursorPath.append(win32api.GetCursorPos())
            time.sleep(.02)   

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        self.isRecording = False

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def play(self):
        for pos in self.cursorPath:
            win32api.SetCursorPos(pos)
            time.sleep(.02)        
        print "Playback complete!"

class CursorCapture(QtGui.QWidget):

    sigRecord = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    sigPlay = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    sigStop = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(CursorCapture, self).__init__()

        self.mouseRecorder = MouseRecord()
        self.myThread = QtCore.QThread()

        self.mouseRecorder.moveToThread(self.myThread)

        self.sigRecord.connect(self.mouseRecorder.record)
        self.sigPlay.connect(self.mouseRecorder.play)
        self.sigStop.connect(self.mouseRecorder.stop)

        self.myThread.start()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.recordBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Record")
        self.stopBtn   = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
        self.playBtn   = QtGui.QPushButton("Play")        

        self.recordBtn.clicked.connect(self.record)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.stop)
        self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.stateLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Status: Stopped.")

        #Bunch of other GUI initialization ...

    def record(self):
        self.stateLabel.setText("Status: Recording ...")  
        self.sigRecord.emit()

    def play(self):
        self.stateLabel.setText("Status: Playback initated ...")
        self.sigPlay.emit()

    def stop(self):
        self.stateLabel.setText("Status: Recording Stopped...")
        self.sigStop.emit()
```

This will allow the `QThread` to be always running (which isn't a problem as it's not doing anything unless you tell it to) with your `MouseRecorder` instance waiting for signals from your gui thread.

Notice the additional need for the `QApplication::processEvents()`.